# Get Child count for selected node

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I try to go over an xml file and delete some attributes , I succeed doing that
but I want an option to select the one that I want to delete
so I thought about a list box that will show all the attributes
so that I can use their ID and Value

when I use FOR EACH statement I can use `foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode child in xn)`
then I can use `child.Attributes.Count` for counting the amount of attributes 
and then I can loop until i reach this number ( that's what I do when I delete the nodes )
but the loop is for each node in the XML
but I want to use it once just to fill the listbox
please help
thanks.[image]

here is the example XML ( Can't show the values , sorry )
what I expat to see in the list are the attribute names , as selected in red

[image]

```
<VolSurface xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MTM Currency="" Spot="" ISIN="" Exchange="" EquityName="" CutOff="" ValuationDate="">
        <Maturity ATMFVolatility="" VarSwap="" DividendYieldPercent="" ATMSVolatility="" VolatilitySpread="" DepoRate="" SumOfDividends="" SecLendingRate="" ForwardRate="" TenorDate="" Tenor="">
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
            <Strike Put="" Call="" Vol="" Strike="" Value=""/>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. Could you show some sample XML and an example of what you want to see?

Comment: How are the two events (button clicks) exactly connected to each other? In the button1_click handler the attributes of the second node _Node[1] are taken? What and where exactly is the problem?

Comment: first button , I load the file path + I want to print the attributes , that Later I can remove and save with the second button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found my answer !!
instead of selecting a list I had to select only one node and use it's COUNT

```
XmlNode _Node = _Doc.SelectSingleNode("/VolSurface/MTM/Maturity");
int _CNode = _Node.Attributes.Count;
```

in this instance I was taking ALL the node available ( it was about 150+ nodes )
and for each node I was looping for attributes

```
XmlNodeList xn = _Doc.SelectNodes("/VolSurface/MTM/Maturity");
```

Any way ,
THANKS FOR THE HELP :)